# How to upload multiple files to HDFS via KNOX WebHDFS gateway?

Tags: webhdfs, knox-gateway, apache-knox

I have KNOX gateway setup for our Hadoop cluster and I have gone through KNOX WebHDFS examples. So far, I know that the below cURL commands can be used to create a directory and upload a **single** file.

```
curl -k -u username:password -X PUT https://localhost:8443/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/user/testuser?op=MKDIRS
curl -i -k -u username:password -X PUT 'https://localhost:8443/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/user/testuser/file1?op=CREATE'
curl -i -k -u username:password -T file1 -X PUT '{Value of Location header from command above}'
```

Now if I want to upload three files, say `file2`, `file3`, `file4` to the HDFS location `/user/testuser`, I have to execute the last two commands (from above) three times for three files respectively.

I want to know a way through which I can upload multiple files in a single go. Is there a way I could provide multiple files as input in one `PUT` request? If there is none, I'm even okay with moving the files to a folder and the upload that folder instead with a single `PUT` request.

Comment: I am not sure if you need Value of Location header in step 3. According to [Knox user guide](http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-8-0/user-guide.html#WebHDFS), "Direct WebHDFS requests may return Location headers that contain the address of a particular DataNode. The gateway will rewrite these URLs to ensure subsequent requests come back through the gateway and internal cluster details are protected." I haven't, but will soon, verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Knox proxies the WebHDFS APIs. I do not think WebHDFS has the ability to upload multiple files or non-empty directory see [WebHDFS File and Directory Operations](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#File_and_Directory_Operations) so most likely you won't be able to do that.

The other option is to use a script (a bash script) that uses multiple PUT requests.